# How do I block a person in Fiesta online?

Tags: fiesta-online

I have found HOWTOs about how the system works, but not a single article how to actually *block* someone.

([Not-helping guide](http://www.outspark.com/forums/showthread.php?t=122587))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Options are available by right-clicking on individual users in the
>   chat window: whisper, add as friend, party invite and block. If you
>   choose to block a player, you'll no longer receive any messages from
>   them.

Right click them in the chat window and choose block.

http://fiesta-online.gamigo.com/first_steps/interface/